# Change microphone button from start/stop to mute/unmute

Tags: macos, catalina, audio, settings

I have an external microphone with a single button.

When I click it, it controls the start/stop of music; double click jumps to the next song.

I want to change that to mute/unmute the microphone, since for a different microphone i also have this is what that button does.

How do I do that on MacOSX?

EDIT: Posted on apple forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251754266